GU/Ferco multi point lock stuck
my 3 point lock has issues.  Recently the bottom bolt would not retract and thus my door was locked shut.  I had to take out the hinge pins and kick the door open.  When inspecting the bottom slider seemed to have slipped off the middle latch mechanism that slides the lock open…..  I put it back together and it worked fine again for a few days and then slipped off again.  I did this yet again and same thing….  The mechanism that slides the bottom latch up and down sips off the notch and keep the door locked on the bottom bolt only….  How do I fix?
Thx

No idea how one could diagnose this one remotely. Something is loose, worn, misaligned or damaged, but finding the problem requires hands on examination.
